# growth function of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can someone tell how to prove that the growth function of the additive group of integers is polynomially upper bounded? It's my intuition that it is not polynomially upper bounded, but I can't prove it! Maybe it's very simple, but I got stuck, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know growth function only in the context of families of sets, but what is meant here?

Comment: The number of elements within distance $n$ of the identity is $2n+1$. Thus the growth function is very clearly polynomially (linearly) bounded.

Comment: I still don't get it!! Can this be explained in more details? Please help!!!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_(group_theory)

Answer (score 3):

Take the symmetric generating set $\{+1,-1\}$. Pick a sequence of up to $n$ elements and add them up. The sequence consists of $+1$'s and $-1$'s, say $k$ of $+1$ and $l$ of $-1$, where $k,l \in \{0,1,...,n\}$ and $k+l \le n$.  The sum equals 
$$k \cdot (+1) + l \cdot (-1) = k-l \in \{-n,-n+1,...,n-1,n\}
$$
so the sum is one of the $2n+1$ integers from $-n$ to $n$. The growth function is therefore bounded above by the 1st degree polynomial function $2n+1$.